# "error: expected identifier before numeric constant" when trying to define a std::bitset inside a class

Tags: c++, c++11, std-bitset

I'm trying to create a variable of type `std::bitset<16>` in my class:

```
#include <bitset>

class foo{
public:
    std::bitset<16> bar (0xfa2);
};
```

But the program fails to compile with the following error:

```
$ g++ src/test.h 
src/test.h:5:26: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
    5 |     std::bitset<16> bar (0xfa2);
      |                          ^~~~~
src/test.h:5:26: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before numeric constant
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. The bitset definition is copied straight from the documentation [example](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/bitset/) so I don't think it should throw any error. I've been trying to fix this for a while, but only noticed that the program compiles if I initialize the bitset without any argument, which is not what I'm trying to do anyways.

Comment: It looks like your compiler is parsing `bar` as a function returning `std::bitset<16>` instead of a variable. Change `std::bitset<16> bar (0xfa2);` to `std::bitset<16> bar {0xfa2};`

Comment: `The bitset definition is copied straight from the documentation` No, it is not copied straight. The context is different. You should learn initialization of class members.

Comment: @drescherjm You're right. That's it. If you want, you can turn your comment into an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I think this is an instance of the [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).  There is an entire [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/most-vexing-parse) about it.

Comment: There are duplicates for vexing parse which we could close this with. However with that said if you don't know about vexing parse you are highly unlikely to find the duplicate via a search.

Comment: @NateEldredge It's not the most vexing parse; that declaration cannot be parsed as a function declaration. It's just that a [*default member initializer*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization) must use brace-or-equals initializer, and can't use parentheses.